# Deleting Contacts from Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder

Recently we merged contacts in Salesforce and deleted 4 million duplicate records from salesforce. Now we would like to delete the same records from SFMC.I know once we deleted those records , they would not have synced back to marketing cloud and our synchronized data extension in SFMC would automatically get rid of those merged records. But those customers would be in “All Contacts” which would count against our Contacts and we would like to delete them from All contacts. How should we go about it considering we have 72 million records in All Contacts?Also if I run left join on All Contacts and synchronized data extension,it times out.

Just to add,I am not just trying to identify the numbers of contacts but i have identified them and facing issue with the volume of data. Also I have deleted the customers from Salesforce and i use person account there. Does it make sense to compare All contacts with synchronized DE contacts_salesforce?I only want to filter those 4 million (which i had merged in CRM) from the All contacts.

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesnot .I have already filtered the list from mobile connect but the list has 46 million contacts. I am not able to open it in excel or anything. I need to compare the list with my contacts_ salesforce table .I have the 4 million personcontactIds list as well that i had deleted from salesforce.

Comment: You should use the query to break the list up in <1million records. Or a query that joins the list to contacts_salesforce. You can also add a filter where contactid is null in contacts_salesforce

Comment: Thanks @EazyE I only want to filter those 4 million customers(that i had deleted) from All contacts.

Comment: Also if I have the contactIds(4 million) which i have deleted ,even if i identify them how would I delete  them in bulk from All contacts?